# Parametrize by type constructor?

Tags: haskell

I made a tree structure (`Tree`) that represents an algebraic expression that contains two binary opperators the "question mark" `Q`/`"?"` and the "exclamation mark" `E`/`"!"`.

Both are associative (that means `a!(b!c)=(a!b)!c`, and the same for the questionmark; this means the order of evaluation doesn't matter and we can omit the parenthesis if we have a chain of the same operator), we do however have no precedence rules, that means we have to use parenthesis if we have a mix of operators: `a?b!c` would be invalid, it must be `(a?b)!c` or `a?(b!c)`.

So now I wanted to make it a `Show` instance that prints out this expression in one line according to the rules outlined above. For that I wrote some helper functions `surroundX` that add parenthesis where needed.

So my question is: Is there a way to reduce the duplicated code, especially in the `surroundX` functions?

I thought that it would be nice to be able to pass `E` or `Q` as an additional parameter, but I didn't find a way to make that work. But maybe there are other ways to simplify this.

```hs
data Tree = Unit | E Tree Tree | Q Tree Tree

surroundE a@(E _ _) = "(" ++ show a ++ ")"
surroundE x = show x
surroundQ a@(Q _ _) = "(" ++ show a ++ ")"
surroundQ x = show x

instance Show Tree where
 show Unit = "1"
 show (E a b) = surroundQ a ++ "!" ++ surroundQ b
 show (Q a b) = surroundE a ++ "?" ++ surroundE b

--example output
main = do
 print $ E (E Unit Unit) (E Unit (Q Unit Unit))
 print $ Q (E Unit Unit) (Q Unit (Q Unit Unit))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBBDsIgFET3nGIkLmyMCw9gdMMBiLo2X0vSxkobSmMX3r1@qLbVuHBD@MM8ZiCj@mqKoutS8oSDMwYbHG3u8YDq57g8oMdJiLpxrmxsqkC7hcIJp4Q5uZBYLlFn5R0UdjKRE2vLlnjWDqIOvP6L11Ne5Lb2ZC8G@yDEZvfMOCN6R3wBX7iWL4FLEs4hZBIdI2Z95qCe34T@JtSL2H4QigmxWpmWblVhUDa@ary4UW4ZTUuByuXWY87fySVisbAkw8RBo5qMfv3t17/8XfcE)

Comment: Your code is very concise so there's little room for improvement. That being said I would consider changing the constructors so something like `data Tree = Unit | Subtree Kind Tree Tree`. `Kind` could be the argument for `surround` and produce connecting symbol in `show`.

Comment: @bdecaf Thanks for your comment! This change change in the definition of the `Tree` makes it a lot easier to handle, also for other applications one might have. I think your suggestion covers exactly what I was asking for. So please consider adding it as an anwer!

Comment: you are most welcome. I don't bother about the points, and as your question is already solved I don't want to put in more research. I'd suggest you post your simplified code and self answer.

Answer (score 5):

### Food for thought:

From my (now deleted) comment:
Your operators are associative, but your data structure is not. Is there a different data representation which is associative?

I think you want to do more with this tree than just printing it, right?
The problem is you want `Q Unit (Q Unit Unit)` to be equal to `Q (Q Unit Unit) Unit`. Find a 'canonical' representation!

Think about an answer or scroll down to find mine. The next steps just set it up.

### Pulling out the operator?

You've already seen this in the comment:

```
data Operator = ExclamationMark | QuestionMark
data Tree = Unit | BinaryNode Operator Tree Tree
```

### Type parameters

Your example seems to be a minimal working example, but you certainly want your `Unit` to contain some identifier, e.g. `data BinTree a = Leaf a | BinaryNode Operator BinTree BinTree`. Do the same with `Operator` and you've got:

```
data BinTree op a = Leaf a | BinaryNode op (BinTree op a) (BinTree op a)
```

Based on your haskell experience, you might want to write your `Functor`, `Applicative`, `Monad` and `Traversable` instances.

The type parameter `op` can be instantiated with `Operator`, but maybe also `String` in the context of (pretty-)printing. Or go further and have a function in place of `op`:

```
evalBinTree :: BinTree (a -> a -> a) a -> a
evalBinTree (Leaf x)                  = x
evalBinTree (BinaryNode f left right) = f (eval left) (eval right)
```

of course get yourself a function to make these tasks easier:

```
mapOp :: (op -> op') -> BinTree op a -> BinTree op' a
```

### Associativity Hint

`data Binary a = Binary a a` is isomorphic to a pair `(a,a)`, which always contains two `a`s. What data structure allows you to have an arbitrary number of `a`s? Next section is some sort of filler to hide the solution.

### Haskell philosophy

Haskell is a functional language. While "functional" puts the emphasis on functions, it is actually data-centric. Defining new data structures and converting between them is easier and more concise than in, say, Java. What I am trying to say here: You can keep the `BinTree` and the `AssocTree` of the following section and write functions that transforms one representation to the other.

### Associativity Solution

First a non-parametric data type that allows an arbitrary number of children:

```
data AssocTree = Unit | Node [AssocTree]
```

but I will continue with:

```
data AssocTree op a = ALeaf a | ANode op [AssocTree op a]
```

And left as an exercise, you want a function:

```
toAssocTree :: BinTree op a -> AssocTree op a
```

But `toAssocTree` cannot collect your associative operators. That needs equality on `op`:

```
collectAssoc :: (Eq op) => AssocTree op a -> AssocTree op a
```

This way, you divide your computation into little steps.

### Why turn `Operator` into a type parameter `op`

Here is the reason why I supposed to make the operation a type parameter: With an abstract type, the type system prevents this error:

```
data BTree = Unit | E Tree Tree | Q Tree Tree
data ATree = AUnit | AE [Tree]  | AQ [Tree]
toATree (E left right) = AE [left,right]
toATree (Q left right) = AE [left,right] -- c&p error: should be AQ, not AE
```

Yes, abstracting out the type prevents errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your insights! I now do think converting the binary tree to an associative one does make a lot of sense, especially in light of the paragraph you wrote about the data-centricity of Haskell.

Answer (score 2):

Placing the recursion in show and adding the operator character as an extra parameter simplifies the helper function.

```hs
data Tree = Unit | E Tree Tree | Q Tree Tree

instance Show Tree where
  show Unit = "1"
  show (E a@(Q _ _) b) = showExp "!" (surround (show a)) (show b)
  show (E a b@(Q _ _)) = showExp "!" (show a) (surround (show b))
  show (E a b) = showExp "!" (show a) (show b)
  show (Q a@(E _ _) b) = showExp "?" (surround (show a)) (show b)
  show (Q a b@(E _ _)) = showExp "?" (show a) (surround (show b))
  show (Q a b) = showExp "?" (show a) (show b)

showExp op a b = a ++ op ++ b

surround t = "(" ++ t ++ ")"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9BDoIwFET3/xRj44KGlQcgrjhAox6gSBMasRBoggvuXn@rQKJsJp35r7/TRo8P07Yh1NprXAdjUODmrMeM8uOTzFCbI7Ju9NrdDS5NN30GU2MGQ8AYk7ShgDiJJclKaFSSw2jLVw9xEMjSTMvvoZIrrv7w8x5Oy7jr44X4ZiaQ52xYOGStoggpiOiprWOm7gj9YJ3HkX/J1VLfKHJ13GBL5carX17t8SG8AQ)

Edit: Taking into account associativity by pattern matching in show.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Please do note though that your snippet does not the actually  preseve the behaviour of the original one: Yours parenthesizes ALL operators, so for the first example we get `((1!1)!(1!(1?1)))` instead of `1!1!1!(1?1)`.